# Is this namespace collision due to a bug in the XAML to .NET code generation?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, namespaces

Below I describe how to reproduce an error I'm receiving.  It behaves the same in VS 2010, 2012, and 2013.  Breaking it into multiple projects, as I indicate below, is important.

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. Create a solution.
2. Create a C# class library called Common, containing one file named Handler.cs:

   ```
   using System;

   namespace Common
   {
       public delegate void Handler(object sender, EventArgs args);
   }
   ```
3. Create a WPF user control library project called MyControlLibrary, referencing Common.  In it, create a user control called MyControl.xaml.

   MyControl.xaml:

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="ControlNamespace.MyControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
       <Grid>

       </Grid>
   </UserControl>
   ```

   MyControl.xaml.cs:

   ```
   using System.Windows.Controls;
   using Common;

   namespace ControlNamespace
   {
       public partial class MyControl : UserControl
       {
           public MyControl()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

           public event Handler MyEvent;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create a WPF Application project called MyWpfApplication, referencing Common and MyControlLibrary.  In it, create WindowNamespace.Common.cs as well as a window called MyWindow.xaml.

   WindowNamespace.Common.cs:

   ```
   namespace WindowNamespace.Common
   {
   }
   ```

   MyWindow.xaml:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="WindowNamespace.MyWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ControlNamespace;assembly=WpfControlLibrary1"
           Title="MyWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
       <Grid>
           <c:MyControl MyEvent="MyControl_MyEvent" />
       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```

   MyWindow.xaml.cs:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Windows;

   namespace WindowNamespace
   {
       public partial class MyWindow : Window
       {
           public MyWindow()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

           void MyControl_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
           {
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Build the solution.

You should receive the following error, pointing to line 7 of MyWindow.xaml:

> The type or namespace name 'Handler' does not exist in the namespace
>   'WindowNamespace.Common' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

If you open the .g.i.cs file generated for MyWindow.xaml, you should see the following in the IComponentConnector.Connect method:

```
#line 7 "..\..\MyWindow.xaml"
((ControlNamespace.MyControl)(target)).MyEvent += new Common.Handler(this.MyControl_MyEvent);
```

The source of the issue is that it is trying to find Common.Handler in WindowNamespace.  This could be resolved by having it generated as:

```
#line 7 "..\..\MyWindow.xaml"
((ControlNamespace.MyControl)(target)).MyEvent += new global::Common.Handler(this.MyControl_MyEvent);
```

Or by adding a using to the top of the file:

```
using Common;

...

#line 7 "..\..\MyWindow.xaml"
((ControlNamespace.MyControl)(target)).MyEvent += new Handler(this.MyControl_MyEvent);
```

Note that if all these source files are bundled into a single project, the error goes away, because the .g.i.cs file is generated differently (i.e. it doesn't explicitly add the handler to the event).

Is this actually a bug in the XAML->.NET translation, or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort into reproducing this issue.  Too bad there aren't any solutions, yet.  It would seem that some **clr-namespace:...** adjustment to allow **global:** in the namespace would fix problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's a clue as to what's happening if you redeclare the Handler delegate in your WindowNamespace.Common namespace declaration in MyWpfApplication and try to compile:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'WindowNamespace.Common.Handler' to 'Common.Handler' c:\Dev\YourSolution\MyWpfApplication\MyWindow.xaml  7   63  MyWpfApplication
```

The Common project is declaring a global namespace called "Common", which your control library is also using. But when your application explicitly declares "WindowNamespace.Common" it creates a local namespace which just so happens to be the same namespace that the parent control resides in. This effectively creates the ambiguity problem described in the [Visual Studio documentation for Compiler Error CS0433](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64wh5743%28v=vs.110%29).

Change your common namespace declaration in MyWpfApplication to just be "Common" and the problem will go away.

Comment: You are correct about the nature of the namespace collision, that it's assuming Common refers to the one that exists within the current namespace rather than the global Common.  However, two namespaces sharing the same name is ... common, and C# offers mechanisms for resolving these clashes without having to rename one of them.  These mechanisms simply cannot be used in this case since I'm not the one writing the C#, unless XAML exposes a way to do this.

Comment: I assume you've already considered and rejected aliasing then? You might have to provide more details then on which parts you do have control over. Either way I doubt this counts as a compiler bug, it's using the namespace you're giving it. Can you not bind the event to a ICommand or something and resolve the collision in code?

Comment: I'm unclear on how aliasing could help here; could you clarify?  I don't specify the type that's failing to resolve, so I don't have the opportunity to provide a namespace alias.  That's specified only in the code that's generated to assign the event handler based on the XAML event binding.